# Changing x-axis tick labels when working with subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am plotting multiple boxplots on a single figure using matplotlib following the example here:
 http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html

Everything is working as expected, but I can't figure out how to change the tick labels on the x-axis. I have four data series, which are plotting, but the x-axis ticks are labelled '1, 2, 3, 4' where I would like to assign text to these values.

My code for the plotting looks like this:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
axarr[0].boxplot(WS_Bias, whis = 100)
#axarr[0].xticks(range(1, len(Labels)+1),Labels)
axarr[0].axhspan(-0.5, 0.5, facecolor='c', alpha = 0.2)

axarr[1].boxplot(WS_RMS, whis = 100)
#axarr[1].xticks(range(1, len(Labels)+1),Labels)
axarr[1].axhspan(0, 2, facecolor='c', alpha = 0.2)

pl.show()
```

The commented out lines worked to change the labels when I was dealing with only one dataset but this command is not recognized with the methods I'm using. Pyplot is imported as plt.

Comment: With labels you mean "ticklabels" right? If it's so (and I think it is), edit the title and text to use "ticklabels". Axis labels are the name of the variable associated with the axis, not the numbers `1,2,3,..`

Comment: Thanks, I updated it accordingly.  You are correct, I'm trying to change the actual tick labels.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let's assume that `axarr[0]` has 4 visible `x tick labels` (`[1,2,3,4]`) and that you want to have instead ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

You can set x tick labels with the `Axes` method [`set_xticklabels`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) just doing this:

```
axarr[0].set_xticklabels(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Regarding

> The commented out lines worked to change the labels when I was dealing with only one dataset but this command is not recognized with the methods I'm using

`xticks` is not an `Axes` method but a function in `matplotlib.pyplot`, that (I think) wraps `set/get_xticks` and `set/get_xtickslabels`. So if you try to use it as in your code, you should get an error.